# Rarely used values in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, mongoose, schema

I have a users document specified in via mongoose schema, and internally I want to store a few values in the mongodb document such as flags for various things, such as "has_sent_welcome_email".
None of these flags values will ever be seen inside the web-app directly, but will have external reporting which will read them.

An example of the use case is:

1. User registers, we create and save new document using mongoose user
   model.
2. We attempt to send automated email response, but our email
   server errors for some reason so we set flag to indicate welcome was
   never sent.

This can refer various other flags we have, but this is the sort of scenario I am referring to.

Should I store these in the mongoose user schema?

It seems a bit of a waste if they are never going to be displayed, however setting the flag seems easier if I do. Can/should I have the flags as a separate model/schema? Are there any best practices around this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

I think its fine to store those flags in the user schema. As those flag are related to user ,the cardinality is few (for boolean is only true or false), and the most important is that easier for you to implement

You should concern about separate model/schema when you have a "one-to-many" relationship like 1 city has millions of user. Otherwise, embedded field in a schema is prefered. Because its easier to do, and you can get all data in one query

For you app, if you dont want mongo to return the extra field you can use projection (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) to reduce to network transfer between server and your web-app to reduce network transfer between your server and web-app